# Meaning of sd argument in R function: "sd="

Tags: r, arguments, standards, deviation

the "mixedDesign" function was written by the professor for this homework, but I think the argument "sd" is standard as I've found it on other functions but with no description of what the value should actually describe. What am I actually saying when I designate a value for sd? Professor says 0.1 is "too low". Is there a standard value for this argument?

```
simdata  <- mixedDesign(B=c(2, 2), W=2, n=10, M=Means, 
            SD=0.1, R=.42, empirical = TRUE, long = TRUE)
```

I'm aware that standard deviation is 34.1% either side of the mean!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How on earth do you expect us to answer that?  Ask your professor or show us the entire function definition.

Comment: Because, as I said, 'I think the argument "sd" is standard' - but it is apparently not?! I'll have a look...

Comment: The argument `SD=` it not "standard"

Comment: There aren't "standard" arguments. That's not a thing.

Comment: No.  Guessing from the rest of the context, this is some sort of function for simulating data for an experimental design to be fed into a mixed-model analysis.  `SD` **might** be specifying a residual standard deviation.  But as other commenters have said, there's just not enough to go on here.

Comment: Many thanks, Ben Bolker and others. I think I've figured it out. And I'll try to be a little more specific with future questions...

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling leads [here](https://github.com/SilviaMakowski/Shrinkage/blob/master/inst/mixedDesign.R):

> SD:     Matrix specifying the cell standard deviations of crossing between- and within-subject factors (dimensions: prod(B)-by-prod(W) matrix)
>   (for pure within-subjects designs, it is possible to input a vector of size prod(W) as an alternative to a 1-by-prod(W) matrix) OR
>   a scalar (single number) that will be the standard deviation of all cells